# SQL Difference function between Name Column in 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cross-join

I have 2 tables that contain a column for a name part, i.e. John Doe has a row for John and one for Doe.  The 2 tables have different names in them.  I need to take the name part from one table and calculate the DIFFERENCE score to the name part in the other.  Right now I'm using an inner and outer cursor to loop through each of the two tables.  This works but is taking a long time to run.

Is there a different way that would speed this up?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

Table 1

```
Name
----
John
Doe
Jan
Smith
```

Table 2

```
Name
-----
Henry
Ford
Ransom
Eli
Olds
```

This is what I need:

```
DIFFERENCE('John','Henry')
DIFFERENCE('John','Ford')
DIFFERENCE('John','Ransom')
DIFFERENCE('John','Eli')
DIFFERENCE('John','Olds')
DIFFERENCE('Doe','Henry')
DIFFERENCE('Doe','Ford')
DIFFERENCE('Doe','Ransom')
DIFFERENCE('Doe','Eli')
DIFFERENCE('Doe','Olds')
DIFFERENCE('Jane','Henry')
DIFFERENCE('Jane','Ford')
DIFFERENCE('Jane','Ransom')
DIFFERENCE('Jane','Eli')
DIFFERENCE('Jane','Olds')
DIFFERENCE('Smith','Henry')
DIFFERENCE('Smith','Ford')
DIFFERENCE('Smith','Ransom')
DIFFERENCE('Smith','Eli')
DIFFERENCE('Smith','Olds')
```

Right now, I save these DIFFERENCE scores in a temp table for testing purposes.  Sorry for the lack of formatting, I'm new to posting here.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I have one table with over 28,000 records and am comparing it to another table with over 5,000 records.  Unless I'm doing my math wrong, that will generate over 160,000,000 combined records and take over 3.5 hours to process.  Is there a faster process to reduce the amount of time it may take?  Thanks.

Comment: @carl20236 As you are rather new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a cartesian join.. or CROSS JOIN.

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE(t1.Name, t2.Name) 
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

[**For Reference**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

Answer (score 5):

I think - what you are actually are looking for - is [`CROSS JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx).

It is - in short - a *join-everything-with-everything* join which needs no join condition. The result is each possible combination of values, in other words: the *cartesian product*.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES
 ('John')
,('Doe')
,('Jan')
,('Smith');

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES
 ('Henry')
,('Ford')
,('Ransom')
,('Eli')
,('Olds');

SELECT t1.Name
      ,t2.Name
      ,DIFFERENCE(t1.Name,t2.Name) AS DiffName
FROM @tbl1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN @tbl2 AS t2
```

The result

```
Name    Name    DiffName
John    Henry   2
Doe     Henry   2
Jan     Henry   2
Smith   Henry   2
John    Ford    2
Doe     Ford    2
Jan     Ford    2
Smith   Ford    2
John    Ransom  1
Doe     Ransom  0
Jan     Ransom  1
Smith   Ransom  1
John    Eli     2
Doe     Eli     2
Jan     Eli     2
Smith   Eli     1
John    Olds    0
Doe     Olds    0
Jan     Olds    0
Smith   Olds    1
```

Comment: upvoted because of documentation, ready to test code and result. another way: `SELECT T1.Name, T2.Name, DIFFERENCE(T1.Name, T2.Name) AS 'Difference'
FROM (VALUES ('John'),('Doe'),('Jan'),('Smith')) T1 (Name)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('Henry'),('Ford'),('Ransom'),('Eli'),('Olds')) T2 (Name)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to write it that's even simpler:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name, DIFFERENCE(table1.Name, table2.Name)
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: It is correct, that the simple, comma separated list of  `FROM`-sources without any `WHERE`-clause will create exactly the same as `CROSS JOIN`. But there are examples why `CROSS JOIN` should be prefered, especially if it comes to further joins or `APPLY`s. If this is *even simpler* is a matter of taste actually...

Comment: @Shnugo what are the examples?

Comment: Use the full code of my answer and add one more line `CROSS APPLY(SELECT t1.Name+t2.Name AS Combined) AS x`. Add `x.Combined` to the select list. This will work and show both names concatenated. Now try with the comma and find `t1.Name` out of scope...